# Cannot access contents of NSMutableArray when calling from a different class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I want to have an array that is accessible throughout my Objective-C project whose contents I can change where necessary. My problem is that when I call the array from a different class I  always get null, and that's not what I want.

In my .h file I have

```
@interface MainScreen2 : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Judith;
```

and in the viewDidLoad function on the .m file I have:

```
@interface MainScreen2 ()

@end

@implementation MainScreen2
@synthesize Judith;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.Judith = [[NSMutableArray alloc]     initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9", nil];                                                    
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

this is fine.

In a separate class I have:

```
#import "MainScreen2.h"

@interface NewGame ()
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MainScreen2 *testJudith;

    NSMutableArray *testJudithArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    testJudithArray = [testJudith.Judith mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"Jud test: %@", [testJudith.Judith objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

and the `NSLog` returns null for this point. Is this because when I am calling the Judith array from the MainScreen.h file it is empty at this point because it is not yet loaded?

If so, can anyone help me with where I should be putting the array so when I call it I retain it's original contents?

---

EDIT: 30 Apr

Using a combination of the suggestions kindly put on this page I have now sorted out the problem and it now works.

```
I changed the code to the following:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
MainScreen2 *testJudith = [[MainScreen2 alloc]init];
[testJudith viewDidLoad];
NSString *test = [testJudith.Judith objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"Jud test: %@", test);
}
```

thanks to all that contributed to the forum post!

Comment: You should not call `-viewDidLoad` directly, instead you should let it be called by `-loadView`.  Calling it directly might cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is not the same as `init`...you either move the allocation of the NSArray in `init` or you call `[testJudith viewDidLoad];`

Comment: You should not call `-viewDidLoad` directly, you should let it be called from `loadView`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this code:

```
MainScreen2 *testJudith;
NSMutableArray *testJudithArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
testJudithArray = [testJudith.Judith mutableCopy];
```

There are two *serious* problems with this code.

1. `testJudithArray` is initialized, and then it is initialized again.  The first value is discarded.  Unless you are using ARC, that is a memory leak.  Either way, there is no point to initializing it twice.
2. `testJudith` is **not** initialized.  If you were lucky, the program would crash.  You were unlucky, so the program gave you incorrect results instead.

You will have to initialize `testJudith` for your code to work.

Comment: Great answer, but for #2 if you send a message to nil (as all ARC objects are set to automatically), it just returns nil silently. So really if you break it down to `[[testJudith Judith] mutableCopy]` it evaluates to `[nil mutableCopy]` which evaluates to `nil`, which is a valid value to assign to a mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

You've said: `MainScreen2 *testJudith;` which sets testJudith to nil.

You then created an array:

```
NSMutableArray *testJudithArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

You then RESET testJudithArray to a mutable copy of testJudith's Judith array:

```
testJudithArray = [testJudith.Judith mutableCopy];
```

But testJudith is nil. You haven't set it as anything. Which means the property of nil will always be/return nil. You then try to make a mutableCopy of nil. Thus, testJudithArray becomes nil.

You have not created a testJudith to begin with, so you then never create the array you are asking to make a mutable copy of. The mutableCopy method thus returns nil (as any message sent to nil returns nil).

Does this explain enough where your error is?

Comment: Since when does `MainScreen2 *testJudith;` in function scope initialize anything it to `nil`?  Is this new?

Comment: Declaring an Objective-C value without setting it automatically sets it as nil. So I could put Random *random; and would be guaranteed the random instance variable will be nil at this stage. In ARC, it is defined as definitive behaviour.

Comment: Is there documentation for this?  (It *definitely* didn't do this before ARC).

Comment: In the Introducing Automatic Reference Counting session (323) from WWDC 2011 mentions at 21 mins in that pointers must be zero initialised. It was a formalisation of best practice.

Comment: @Dietrich: There's a very brief entry about it in Apple's ["Transitioning to ARC"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW5) guide. This _only_ happens when compiling with ARC, and it's _only_ object variables; compiling for MRR, even with the latest clang, still results in undefined values for uninitialized auto variables.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I haven't had a chance to get to my Mac yet but once I do, I will see if I can solve this. I understand what the error is now (thanks for this) and have an idea how to solve it but will have to see when I get back. The joys of learning!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Singleton. You can google singleton to get more information on it. Using a singleton will allow you to access the same strings, arrays, etc... from anywhere in your project.

Create a singleton by adding a new Objective-C class and making it a subclass of NSObject. For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+(MyClass *)sharedInstance;
@end

#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass
+ (MyClass *) sharedInstance
{
if (!_sharedInstance)
{
    _sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
}
return _sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

If you create your NSMutableArray in MyClass, it will be accessible from any other class of your program as long as you #import "MyClass" in the .m file of the class you want access to the singleton.

To access your MyClass array from another class, do this:

```
MyClass *myClass = [MyClass sharedInstance];
NSString *myString = [[myClass someArray] objectAtIndex:1];
```

To add something to your MyClass array, do this:

```
[[myClass someArray] addObject:@"something"];
```